# Setting visibility of asp Validator to True affects no change

Tags: html, asp.net, css, .net

I have a CustomValidator and a RegularExpressionValidator that have their visibility set in the code behind.  I want to do this so that when the page is not a postback the controls do not reserve any space in the html document

**NOTE:** I already tried using the dynamic display setting for the controls, but this does not work for me because it forces an inline style of display:inline which destroys my layout

However this situation works perfectly for requirefieldvalidators that I use in my page.

Here is an example of the control and its validator:

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion="">
    <dd>
        <a href="#PanelProductPricing">Product Pricing and Inventory</a>
        <div id="PanelProductPricing" class="content active">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <%-- SALE PRICE ------------------------------------------%>
                    <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
                        <label>
                            Sale Price
                            <input id="tbPriceSale" type="text" placeholder="Sale Price" runat="server" />
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvPriceSale" ControlToValidate="tbPriceSale" EnableClientScript="true" Text="Please enter a sale price" 
                                CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="AddProduct"
                                OnServerValidate="cvPriceSale_ServerValidate" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPriceSale" Text="Invalid value for sale price"
                                ValidationExpression="^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$" ValidationGroup="AddProduct" CssClass="error" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

So in the **page load** event I have the following:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

    rexvPriceSale.Visible = False
    cvPriceSale.Visible = False

ElseIf Page.IsPostBack = True Then

    rexvPriceSale.Visible = True
    cvPriceSale.Visible = True

End If
```

the following is what gets rendered for the validator controls in the output HTML:

```
<span id="dnn_ctr2601_AddProduct_cvPriceSale" class="error" style="visibility:hidden;">Please enter a sale price</span>
<span id="dnn_ctr2601_AddProduct_rexvPriceSale" class="error" style="visibility:hidden;">Invalidvalue for sale price</span>
```

### The Problem

As you can see, the following style is added to the control style="visibility:hidden;" and the control is not visible but it does take up "Space" in the screen.

I cannot figure out where this style is coming from

I have tried removing the visibility=true from the postback and marking it as false, but the controls render the exact same way no matter what I do.

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out why the validators are renders with visibility:hidden no matter how I set their visibility in the server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an asp:PlaceHolder around them, and set its visibility instead.